# Sponsors business cards are being given to me instead of high res files

Tags: adobe-illustrator, logo, scanning

I Need Avdice ASAP Please!
I'm designing a 2.5 x 6 ft banner for a benefit concert. The people hosting the concert who have asked me to make the banner, has given me business cards of the 20 sponsors instead of the high res files I requested. I was told the previous graphic designer had always just requested all of the business cards and was able to scan them in and add them. I find that questionable. If I scan the business cards in at 600 dpi, would that image look professional on a banner of that size, or is it like I think, and I would have to remake each logo?

Comment: http://www.brandsoftheworld.com <-- Grab logos for major companies in many instances.

Answer (score 1):

I would email the client requesting a logo for each company. It would be a good idea to make a logo requirement sheet for the companies to follow so they send a high enough resolution logo or send a vector version of the logo.

Make sure to tell them that if you do not receive a high-resolution logo then the images will be pixelated when enlarged.

> would that image look professional on a banner of that size

It depends on how far the viewer is from the banner. It also would not look that great if the business cards all had different backgrounds.

When I need a company logo for an event and I am short on time I have reversed image search of the companies logo to see if they have a higher resolution logo on the web. You could also search for "(company name) logo PDF" and see if they have a vector version in a PDF.